# Primality test. Is this program performing faster than all others?

Tags: c++, performance, primes

```
bool is_prime(BigInt num)
{
    if(num == 0 || num == 1 || (num != 2 && num % 2 == 0))
        return false;

        BigInt sq = sqrt(num);

        for(BigInt i = 3; i <= sq; i += 2)
            if(num % i == 0)
                 return false;

       return true;
}
```

We only need to check upto square root.
Proof -> https://scienceparv.blogspot.com/2021/07/mathematics-if-one-divisor-of-dividend.html

Comment: It depends on the size of the numbers you are testing. If you're testing 32-bit integers than your method is reasonably efficient compared to others. If you're testing 1024-bit integers for RSA than your method will never finish in the life of the universe.

Comment: @President James K. Polk 1024-bit integers are very big. Are you sure they are tested for primality?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. You could just read the links in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is doing so called [Trial Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) primality test, which is slow for big numbers. It has time complexity `O(Sqrt(N))` of primitive operations.

If you have really big numbers, 1024 bits or bigger then Trial Division will be a way too slow.

There are two kinds of [Primality Tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) - deterministic and probabilistic. Trial Division is one example of deterministic algorithm. All deterministic algorithms are much slower then probabilitic.

Probabilistic algorithms are never certain about if a number is really prime. But for any small chosen probability `P` they can tell in very little computational time if the number is prime with certainty of this probability. Deterministic algorithm are always certain if a number is prime or not.

There exist faster than yours algorithms of deterministic primality testing, for example [Elliptic Curve Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality), which is fast but difficult to implement. But you can easily test any number for free with fast software like [Primo for Linux](http://www.ellipsa.eu/public/primo/primo.html), this is free software but with closed sources and for Linux only (there is no Windows version at all).

I decided to implement for you from scratch one probabilistic primality test, which is [Fermat Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test), it is very fast and easy to implement in few lines of code, which I did in below C++ code. It has complexity of `O(Log2(N))` which is blazingly fast time even for 20000-bit numbers.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/v5TYqqWP3)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using Word = uint32_t;
using DWord = uint64_t;

Word PowMod(Word a, Word b, Word const & c) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation
    Word r = 1;
    while (b != 0) {
        if (b & 1)
            r = (DWord(r) * a) % c;
        a = (DWord(a) * a) % c;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

Word Rand(Word const & prev, Word const & begin, Word const & end) {
    Word constexpr magic_prime = uint32_t(-1) - 4;
    return Word((DWord(prev) * magic_prime) % (end - begin)) + begin;
}

bool IsFermatProbablePrime(Word const & n, int trials = 32) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test
    if (n <= 16)
        return n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 7 || n == 11 || n == 13;
    Word witness = 2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < trials; ++i) {
        witness = Rand(witness, 2, n - 2);
        if (PowMod(witness, n - 1, n) != 1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    Word const prime_num = 3941362591U, comp_num = 2245837171U;
    std::cout
        << std::boolalpha
        << "num1 is prime: " << IsFermatProbablePrime(prime_num) << ", "
        << "num2 is prime: " << IsFermatProbablePrime(comp_num)  << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
num1 is prime: true, num2 is prime: false
```

(and really first number `prime_num` is prime and second `comp_num` is composite)

You can see that I used two typedefs for `Word` and `DWord`, like this:

```cpp
using Word = uint32_t;
using DWord = uint64_t;
```

This kind of typedefs only allow you to check primality of 32-bit numbers, for your case to check big numbers just replace with:

```cpp
using Word = BigInt;
using DWord = BigInt;
```

to use your class `BigInt` that you already used in your code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this program performing faster than all others?

**No.**

There are faster primality tests than trial division.

For example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adleman%E2%80%93Pomerance%E2%80%93Rumely_primality_test

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test